# why istream::get sets failbit and eofbit together?

Tags: c++, get, eof, istream

I wonder why istream::get sets failbit and eofbit together.

The behaviour of std::getline is different: it sets eofbit when it encounters the end of the file, and failbit when you try to read past the end of the file. So you can write:

```
while (std::getline(is, s) {
  blablabla... // gets executed once after end of file has been reached
}
```

whereas if you define your own getSthg function with std::get

```
std::istream& myOwnGetLine(std::istream& is, std::string& s) {
  char c;
  while (is.get(c)) {
    blablabla...
  }
  return is;
}
```

then:

```
while (myOwnGetLine(is, s)) { // fails if eof has been reached
  blablabla // won't get executed for the last line of the stream
}
```

So: what am I doing wrong? The work-around I came up with is:

```
std::istream& myOwnGetLine(std::istream& is, std::string& s) {
  *if (is.rdstate() & std::ios::eofbit) { 
    is.clear(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
  }*  
  char c;
  while (is.get(c)) {
    blablabla...
  }
  *if (is.rdstate() & std::ios::eofbit) {
    is.clear(std::ios::eofbit);
  }*
  return is;
}
```

but that doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `istream::get` to make a `getline` function will lead to some awkward code inside that function, since as per specification, it sets both `eofbit` and `failbit` when it reeaches end-of-file. The way the standard `istream::getline` solves this problem is by using the `rdbuf()` of the `istream` to inspect values. And it looks like that is probably the only way to solve this problem (aside from manipulating the failure state of the stream, that is)